# How to select SQL join table with not redundancy value

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

Table 1: Input

```
Namecode | Number |  
01          50  
01          49  
02          10  
03          40  
04          100
```

Table 2: Output

```
Namecode | Number |  
01          15  
02          25
```

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Input 
LEFT JOIN Output ON Input.Namecode = Output.Namecode
```

This is the result:

```
Namecode | Number | Namecode | Number  
01          50          01          15  
01          49          01          15  
02          10          02          25  
03          40          NULL       NULL   
04          100         NULL       NULL
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
Namecode | Number | Namecode | Number  
01          50          01          15  
01          49         NULL      NULL  
02          10          02          25  
03          40         NULL      NULL   
04          100        NULL      NULL
```

How can I get this output? I want the Namecode 01 only show 1 row, the row left have no value  because in Output table Namecode 01 only have 1 row

What query do I need to get the result I want?

Comment: Both name code `01` records should be matching.  What is the logic by which only one matches?

Comment: Tag your rdbms.

Answer (score 0):

You seem want to match `max(Namecode)` value if there are duplicate `Namecode`

You can try this query, write a subquery and `left join`

```
SELECT t1.*,t3.* 
from Input t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Namecode,MAX(Number) Number  FROM Input GROUP BY Namecode ) t2 
ON t1.Number = t2.Number 
LEFT JOIN Output t3
on t2.Namecode = t3.Namecode1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w3C44XuB17JpgLv6hKWYE7/0)

**Result**

```
Namecode    Number  Namecode1   Number1
01            50       01        15
02            10       02        25
01            49       null     null
03            40       null     null
04           100       null     null
```